# Opening a file using specific application from Windows Command prompt

Tags: terminal, command-prompt

In Linux you type the command( open fileName -a "application to open the file with") what is equivalence to this in Windows Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

if application in your path environment variable use this :

> application_name "C:\Users\path_of_file"

if not use this :

> "C:\Program Files\path_application" "C:\Users\path_of_file"

Comment: It did not work!! It also opened the file itself not with the required application, This is what I wrote   app.component.html "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3"

Comment: how you try it ?
like this ? 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Excel.exe" "C:\Users\pgs\Documents\Book1.xlsx"`